# Confused about how PHP for loop works

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a `for` loop that displays the first six items in a MySQL database. I then breakout to another piece of code, after which I have another `for` loop that displays the next six items in my database.

Though this is exactly the functionality that I wanted, I am confused as to how it works, and was hoping somebody could clarify for me. How does the second `for` loop know to start off where the first one left off?

My code is as follows:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  $id = $row['id'];
  $title = $row['title'];
  $file = $row['file'];

  // Display items

}
```

The second `for` loop is exactly the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a resultset pointer that is created when you execute a query that returns a result set . Each call to `mysqli_fetch_array` advances the resultset pointer to next record

When you are at the start of second for loop the result set pointer is pointing the 7th record

Comment: Which is why I was confused, as it obviously has nothing to do with the loop at all. Perfect.